# Data Template not injected in ItemContainer

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, itemscontrol

I have an `ItemsControl` class that overrides the following methods:

```
protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
{
    return item is TilePanelItem;
}

protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
{
    return new TilePanelItem();
}
```

I provided the template for `TilePanelItem` which is the container of `ItemsControl`:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="tileItemTemplate" TargetType="my:TilePanelItem">
    <Grid Width="200" Height="100">
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
            <ContentPresenter RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5" />    
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

And the `Style` for it:

```
<Style TargetType="my:TilePanelItem">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource tileItemTemplate}" />
</Style>
```

And finally the instance of my `ItemsControl` with the `DataTemplate`:

```
<my:TileItemsControl x:Name="tileControl" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
    <my:TileItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </my:TileItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <my:TileItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Background="Blue">
                <TextBlock Text="here I am" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </my:TileItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</my:TileItemsControl>
```

The `DataTemplate` that I defined is not injected in `ItemContainer`.  When I run the app, it shows the borders as I declared in `ItemContainter` template but I don't see the `DataTemplate`.

What am I missing?

Thanks a million

Comment: Can you post your code of TilePanelItem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bring the ItemsTemplate in to become the ContentPresenter's ContentTemplate:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="tileItemTemplate" TargetType="my:TilePanelItem">
  <Grid Width="200" Height="100">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
      <ContentPresenter RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5"
        ContentTemplate="{Binding ItemsTemplate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,my:TileItemsControl,1}}" />
    </Border>
  </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```